# split string and replace indices

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a rules like this

```
rule <- "X[,14]<=-0.00479499999999999 & X[,14]<=-0.00490000000000002 & X[,14]>-0.00595499999999993 & X[,14]<=-0.00593499999999991 & X[,96]>0.000395000000000034 & X[,96]<=0.000859999999999972"
```

1. i need to split the rule by index

   rule1 <- "X[,14]<=-0.0047 & X[,14]<=-0.0049 & X[,14]>-0.0059 & X[,14]<=-0.0059
   rule2 <-  X[,96]>0.0003 & X[,96]<=0.0008"
2. and replace the indices with new ones from 1 to 2 in this case

14,96 to 1,2

```
rule1 <- "X[,1]<=-0.0047 & X[,1]<=-0.0049 &
          X[,1]>-0.0059 & X[,1]<=-0.0059  

rule2 <-  X[,2]>0.0003 & X[,2]<=0.0008"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split the 'rule' by `&`', then extract the numeric part with `parse_number` to `split` by using number as a group, then `paste` the `list` elements, and finally use `str_replace_all` from `stringr` to replace the index

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- strsplit(rule, "\\s*\\&\\s*")[[1]]

v2 <- trimws(sapply(split(v1, readr::parse_number(v1)), function(x)
          sub("\\s*\\&\\s*$", "", paste(x, collapse=" & "))))
str_replace_all(v2, setNames(as.character(seq_along(v2)), names(v2)))
```

-output

```
#[1] "X[,1]<=-0.00479499999999999 & X[,1]<=-0.00490000000000002 & X[,1]>-0.00595499999999993 & X[,1]<=-0.00593499999999991"
#[2] "X[,2]>0.000395000000000034 & X[,2]<=0.000859999999999972"
```

Comment: @mr.T sorry, it is based on the example you provided

Comment: @mr.T In the example in your post, string was separated with `\n`.  here it is not